# Converting a date string with leading year into a data in SAS

Tags: sas, format, data-conversion

I've had various success with the input statement converting character strings into dates, but when the date is formatted YY/MM/DD, I can't find the right INFORMAT to get INPUT to convert it to a number.

e.g.

```
data test;
format date DDMMYY10.;
date_string = "22/11/07";
date_no = input(date_string, YYMMDDw.);
date = date_no;
run;
```

I've tried using the [list of SAS INFORMATs](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/etscdc/14.2/etsug/etsug_intervals_sect009.htm) but non of them seem to work when converting this type of date. I can only get INPUT to work with formats like DDMMYY10.

Expected output would be:
date_string "22/11/07"
date_no 22956
date 07/11/2022

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
data test;
format date DDMMYY10.;
date_string = "22/11/07";
date_no = input(date_string, YYMMDD8.);
date = date_no;
put date=;
run;
```

Log:

date=07/11/2022

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise you had to specify the width.